# Python program to manipulate netflix across computers to sync video at the same time

Tags: python, api, video, synchronization, netflix

This might be too nebulous of a question, but hear me out:

My girlfriend and I watch Netflix together during times where we are apart.  We like to sync the shows we watch so that we are watching the same parts at the exact same time.  This, however, can be tedious when there are temporary glitches, or inaccuracies with pressing play at the same time.

I want to create a python script that automates this process.  How should I start?  Is there a Netflix API that would allow this kind of manipulation?  What Python functions would I need to become familiar with?

Sorry if this is a broad question, just looking for some resources to begin this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try pyflix2 im not sure if it will do what youre asking but you can look into it

[Pyflix2](https://pyflix2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

that is the only module i could find there might be an actual Netflix API but you can look into that

I hope this gives you somewhere to start

Good Luck!